# WPF Binding ListBox to ViewModel Collection without binding DataContext directly to the collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, datacontext

I'm trying to set the ItemSource of a ListBox to bind to a collection within a viewmodel, but it won't work unless I make my DataContext directly equal to that collection (ex. `DataContext= vm.colorList`) rather than to just the vm.

Essentially, I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class MosaicBoard
{

    public ObservableCollection<Rectangle> colors = new ObservableCollection<Rectangle>();
    public List<string> testList = new List<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<MosaicCellItem> boardSquares = new ObservableCollection<MosaicCellItem>();

    public MosaicBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            {

                boardSquares.Add(new MosaicCellItem() {Col = j, Row=i});

            }
        }

        colors.Add(new Rectangle() { Width = 90, Height = 90, StrokeThickness = 1, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) });
        testList.Add("test1");
    }
}
```

A View using it that looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private Point startPoint;
    public MosaicBoard vm = new MosaicBoard();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;



    }
 }
```

and XAML that looks like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding colors}" />
```

As I understand it, this should be working by referencing the collection within the viewmodel. To make it work, I have to make `DataContext = vm.colors`, and `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`, but this seems wrong and prevents me from using the other collection in the vm.

I'd really like to know why my {Binding colors} doesn't work in this context.

Comment: WPF data binding works with public properties only. Change the dclaration to `public ObservableCollection<Rectangle> colors { get; } = ...`

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, that did it. A bit embarrassing but thank you. Would you like to make this a post so I can mark it correct when it lets me?

Comment: That's odd, because I searched for similar cases for nearly 40 minutes before making this post. Perhaps the question board would benefit from a less specifically worded question that people are more likely to find when they're using fields instead of properties?